# The hopper will not collect the minecarts

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]I am setting up a train station on minecraft.  I have a cactus at the end of the rail and a hopper under the rail in front of the cactus.  The hopper is not collecting the minecart after it hits the cactus.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! To clarify, can you pick up the hopper? The cactus might be breaking it after it turns into an item. And does the hopper have any free spaces?

Comment: The hopper is empty. I try to attach the screen shot, the file is too large

Comment: Does the hopper pick any other items you throw on top of it? If not, look for power sources around, probably something (say, a solid block with a lever on it, to power the rails) is locking it. Also, press F11 to enter the windowed mode, then take the screenshot, the file size should be much smaller. Or convert the screenshot from .png to .jpg before uploadiing.

Comment: to upload a screenshot, it is too large, try resizing it before uploading. the screenshot does not ned to be 4000x2000 px, 1000x500 should be enough.

Comment: The hopper does not pick up anything